# creating a 2D array of vectors

Tags: c++, vector, 2d

I have been trying to create a 2D array of vector for a game. Here is an example of what I am doing.

```
struct TILE {
    int a;
    char b;
    bool c;
};

TILE temp_tile;

std::vector<TILE> temp_vec_tile;
std::vector<std::vector<TILE>> tile;


for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < 10; y++) {

    temp_tile.a = x;
    temp_tile.b = "a";
    temp_tile.c = false;;

    temp_vec_tile.push_back(temp_tile);
    }

    tile.push_back(temp_vec_tile);
}

// Why does this not work?
int x = tile[3][5].a;
```

Note: I don't want to use Boost for this.

Thanks

Comment: Brian R. Bondy has already solved the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not clearing the internal vector each time.  Probably what you want is to put the internal vector declaration inside of the first for loop.